# Null Pointer Exception while using Java Compiler API

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-compiler-api

MyClass.java:

```
package test;
public class MyClass {
    public void myMethod(){
        System.out.println("My Method Called");
    }
}
```

Listing for SimpleCompileTest.java that compiles the MyClass.java file.

SimpleCompileTest.java:

```
package test;
import javax.tools.*;
public class SimpleCompileTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
String fileToCompile = "test" + java.io.File.separator +"MyClass.java";
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
int compilationResult = compiler.run(null, null, null, fileToCompile);
        if(compilationResult == 0){
            System.out.println("Compilation is successful");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Compilation Failed");
        }
    }
}
```

I am executing the SimpleCompileTest class and getting a NullPointerException. The ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() is returning null. Can someone tell me what is wrong with the code

Comment: can you please edit your code with tags?

Comment: So your problem is that `ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()` returns null?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suspect you're running into [this problem](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6477844) - running the code with a JRE instead of a JDK.

When you run `SimpleCompileTest`, try *explicitly* specifying the version of java.exe you're using as the one in your JDK directory.

Comment: How do you explicitly specify the version of Java.exe you're using as the one in your JDK? I tried `Run As` but it already `Project JRE` selected as the JRE

Comment: @Imray: I'm not sure what you're asking - if that's the selected JRE, that's what will run. If you want a different one, select a different JRE. It sounds like you need to ask a new question with your *exact* problem.

Comment: In your answer you say: "When you run SimpleCompileTest, try explicitly specifying the version of java.exe you're using as the one in your JDK directory." I'm asking, how do you do that?

Comment: @Imray: I'm saying that presumably the "Project JRE" you've got configured is simply not the right one. So edit that configuration.

Answer (score 18):

I got the same error. Maybe I am too late to answer this question, but I share my own experiences, it might help someone else facing the same issue in the future. I was playing around with the source code at [Compile Java Files At Runtime](http://java-bytes.blogspot.in/2012/03/compile-java-files-at-runtime.html?showComment=1339137056112#c3902969466866790373).

I was getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` as it is mentioned. I printed out the Java home directory with `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));`, and noticed my Eclipse was pointing to "`C:\Program Files\Java\jre7`" even after I changed my preferences to use JDK1.7 instead of JRE1.7.

I found a workaround by forcing the usage of JDK1.7 by setting system property like this:

```
System.setProperty("java.home", "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_02");
```

Then I compiled my program and did not get any `NullPointerException`.

Comment: You are great dear. you have solved my problem of last 3 weeks. thanks

Comment: I tried this to make [compilation-toolkit](https://code.google.com/p/compilation-toolbox/) work. I had to use `System.setProperty("java.home", "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_02\jre");` to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have a JRE instead of JDK installed. https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6477844

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
```

was returning null. Even after using

```
System.setProperty("java.home", "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_31");
```

was returning null.

However the issue was simple as this code is in the `Tools.jar` found in `Java\jdk1.8.0_31\lib` if you are using JDK. what i did was to go to `project-->properties-->Java Build Path-->order and export-->` and moved `tool.jar` to the top of other JRE and projects.
This helped me get rid of null hope this help you as well.Happy compiling...:-)

Answer (score 0):

Its working with Java application by expicitily including the tools.jar but for web application not working. Throwing Nullpointer

Answer (score 0):

SUPPLEMENT: The answer above is to set the java.home system property within the program. That works for me too, but it's not a very general solution, since you've hard-coded for one jdk version. The alternative that I'm using now is to give the full path to "java" on the command line when I run the program. Such as (consistent with examples above):

```
C:\\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\java -cp ..\classes path.to.program.myProgram
```

Giving the full path to the jdk version means that's the version that's running the program, so that's the one that will be fetched with ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();