# How to create a method out of the text file?

Tags: java, compilation, on-the-fly

I have a text (`.txt`) file that contains Java code!  I want to create a method that includes this Java code and then call that method through the program.

Can anybody suggest a way to do this?

Comment: I google'd and found this: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2006/jw-0612-dynamic.html

Comment: @Nerdtron Is your Google searching 1999?  `com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(..`  *Shudder* Use the [`JavaCompiler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html)!

Comment: LOL - it was the first result :)  maybe it was the way I worded it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let consider this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/CompileString.htm) what it does actually load the source code, compile and execute the java code by simpler program by using JavaCompiler API.

Comment: Really good! Do you think instead of Putting it in the main method id can put it in for example test method and call method like this?            Method m = clazz.getMethod("test", new Class[] { String[].class });
    Object[] _args = new Object[] { new String[0] };
    m.invoke(null, _args);

Comment: @AndrewThompson this example gives a nullpointerException!! i cant run it!!

Comment: @AndrewThompson Please help me this example has an exception but if this work that's perfect for me!! Thanx

Comment: @KhashayarNapster can you show us the code where this throws this NPE. i mean line number?

Comment: In This Line!! There is NPE!! But I cant Understand why!!!?     compiler.getTask(null, null, null, null, null, fileObjects).call();    In Line 21 of the code!!

Comment: its like ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler(); doesn't return the compiler object.

check this way.
if (compiler == null) {
         throw new NullPointerException("Cannot provide system compiler.");
      }

Comment: did you set JAVA_HOME variable. here is the [instructions how set Java Home and Path](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/how-to-create-java-program#SettingJavahomeAndPath) and another thread is discussed this already [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543439/null-pointer-exception-while-using-java-compiler-api)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`JavaCompiler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html).  It can compile code from a `String`, so I'm sure it could handle code from a text file.

---

> Do you think instead of putting it in the main method I can put it in for example test method and call method like this?

Put it wherever you like.  E.G. see the [STBC](http://pscode.org/stbc/) & especially the [source code](http://pscode.org/stbc/#develop).  It provides a GUI and can compile the code in the text area on button click.

[image: STBC GUI]

---

> this program need tools.jar but jre 7 doesnt have this!!

Did you try reading the documentation that is provided for the STBC?  Notably:

### [System Requirements](http://pscode.org/stbc/#minimumrequirement)

STBC will run on any computer with a version 1.6+ Java <strike>Plug-In</strike>* JDK (AKA SDK).

(*) The API that STBC uses is merely a public interface to the compiler in the `tools.jar` that is distributed only with JDKs (though the 'public JRE' of the JDK also seems to acquire a `tools.jar`). This leads to some unusual requirements in running either the native jar, or the web start app.

---

Or shorter, **no** JRE will have a `JavaCompiler`, only JDKs have them.

Comment: this program need tools.jar but jre 7 doesnt have this!!

Comment: @KhashayarNapster  Set your JAVA_HOME and PATH variables, so that they point to a JDK, not a JRE.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the .txt file to a .java file,
2. add it to your java project
3. Compile the code
4. Execute the methods

Comment: I Want It too be dinamic not to go every each time too copy paste in the editor!!

Answer (score 0):

Load the file in through standard java IO and then have Groovy evaluate it for you:

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy

Answer (score 0):

it's something like quine: 
http://www.nyx.org/%7Egthompso/quine.htm

Comment: Thanx Man But I Dont Get This!! :(