# Is it possible to "manually" create instances of java.lang.Method in Java?

Tags: java, reflection

I know this might sound kinda odd, but I was wondering if it was possible to manually create a `java.lang.Method` at runtime.

And what about `Class<?>`?

Comment: Interested to see why would you do that. Generate code at runtime?

Comment: Use the [`JavaCompiler`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8080955/418556) to compile code in memory.  Then you can do as you wish with the resulting classes and their methods and attributes.  Also curious to know the use-case for this functionality.  Whenever a question starts with *"this might sound kinda odd"* it is a good hint to provide the use-case. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to create a `Class<?>` at runtime using libraries such as:

- [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) (probably the most popular)
- [Javaassist](http://labs.jboss.com/javassist/)
- [BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/)

These, can contain the method that you can retrieve as usually using reflection.

Take also a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2532269/272388

Comment: I'm well aware of those libraries. I just wanted to know whether it would be possible to do it just with Java's reflection.

Comment: No, it is not possible:
`java.lang.reflect:
Provides classes and interfaces for obtaining reflective information about classes and objects.`
And you can use the `ClassLoader` to load classes, but you still have to create the bytecode.