# using java api for compilation

Tags: java, api, console

```
MyClass.java:

package test;
public class MyClass {
 public void myMethod(){
     System.out.println("My Method Called");
 }
 }

  Listing for SimpleCompileTest.java that compiles the MyClass.java file.

  SimpleCompileTest.java:

  package test;
  import javax.tools.*;
   public class SimpleCompileTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   String fileToCompile = "test" + java.io.File.separator +"MyClass.java";
   JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler(); //Line 6
   int compilationResult =  compiler.run(null, null, null, fileToCompile);
            if(compilationResult == 0){
        System.out.println("Compilation is successful");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Compilation Failed");
    }
}
}
```

ERROR

[image: Error]

I am compiling SimpleCompileTest.java and getting this error. HELP!!!

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? You can also provide the code with line numbers - the stack trace points to line 6.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513330/toolprovider-getsystemjavacompiler-returns-null-usable-with-only-jre-install

Comment: @DhanaKrishnasamy but no solution

Comment: @rick: There *is* a solution. Run the program with a JDK instead of a plain JRE.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the correct answer to your problem is, but you should take a look at this [Example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/CompileaJavafilewithJavaCompiler.htm).