# ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() returning null

Tags: java, jar, runtime-compilation

I'm currently trying to compile and execute code at runtime. Everything worked perfectly fine in my IDE (Netbeans), but as soon as I exported my code as a .jar file ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() returned null. Is there a reason why this is working in Netbeans but not in the .jar file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() returns null - usable with only JRE installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513330/toolprovider-getsystemjavacompiler-returns-null-usable-with-only-jre-install)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is only present in JDKs, not in JREs.

Comment: I am aware of that, but is that the reason why it's not working in a .jar?

Comment: And it already worked about half a year ago on a different system in a .jar file.