# ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() --- What does it return and when will it work?

Tags: java

I was trying a code-generating and self-compiling program using Java, but found some issues about the compiler it provided with ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler(). Problems are following:

When running in Eclipse, `Compiler c = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()` successfully returns a compiler and `c.run(null, null, null, "AValidJavaFile.java")` compiles the file, with a zero value returned.

When I export it to a runnable Jar file and try to double click on it, it no longer works, not even if I add the tools.jar to its referenced libraries.

But, when I use `java -jar TheCompiler.jar` in my terminal, it works again even without the tools.jar in the classpath, and now I'm confused with this method. What exactly is this and when exactly will it work?? And is there a way that I can use it in a regular runnable Jar file?

I'm on a Mac, version 10.14.6. Java version is 1.8.0_191.

Comment: Maybe a double click runs the jar in the JRE and in the console you run it in the JDK?
See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513330/toolprovider-getsystemjavacompiler-returns-null-usable-with-only-jre-install

Comment: You are probably right @keuleJ and I see that this method actually looks for the compiler in a jar file which is only installed together with a jdk. I'll try to solve the rest myself. Thanks.