# Nullpointerexception error when using JavaCompiler

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Following is the Java code written in eclipse ide...

```
package compile;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.tools.DiagnosticCollector;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;

public class Execute {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
        StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(
                diagnostics, null, null);
        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager
                .getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(Arrays
                        .asList("F:\\practice java\\project\\KeepingMoreKidsQuiet.java"));
        JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager,
                diagnostics, null, null, compilationUnits);
        boolean success = task.call();

        System.out.println(success);
        if(!success)
            System.out.println(diagnostics.getDiagnostics());
        fileManager.close();
    }
}
```

When I run my Java program, it gives me an error on this line

```
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
```

Error I am getting is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at compile.Execute.main(Execute.java:17)

Can you please tell me how can I solve this error?

Comment: compiler is null? From the api docs for ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() "the compiler provided with this platform or null if no compiler is provided"

Comment: Did you step through with a debugger? You can see which object is null, and trying to figure out why. My bet is `ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();` returns `null`, but make sure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543439/null-pointer-exception-while-using-java-compiler-api

Answer (score 4):

From [`ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html#getSystemJavaCompiler%28%29):

> #### Returns:
>
> the compiler provided with this platform **or `null` if no compiler is provided**

Comment: how can i get rid of this?

Comment: @SuUbha See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543439/null-pointer-exception-while-using-java-compiler-api)

Answer (score 2):

This usually comes when you are running program with JRE and not JDK.

IDE like Eclipse detect JRE path and set it as their run path for Java programs. If you are using Eclipse then inside Build Path set new VM with JDK path (default one uses JRE path)

IF you run directly from command prompt then check your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your compiler reference is null at this line        `JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();`

Try setting %JAVA_HOME%\bin at the start of PATH

Comment: your compiler object is null? An *object* cannot be null. A variable can have a `null` value.

Comment: You could see `null` itself as a special metaphorical object that can be referenced by variables. There is even the `Void` class to represent it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `compiler` is null, also just as a design ocd comment: don't do all that work in your `main` method. Take advantage of `methods` and `classes`

Comment: Thanks to all..The problem is solved...It happened because the Eclipse IDE was pointing to the jre...I changed it to JDK using the following code: System.setProperty("java.home", "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_02");  used in the main() function...

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably running you program with the `JRE` not the `JDK`.  The `ToolProvider` will only be able to provide a compiler if you run it with the `JDK`.

[This is the expected behavior](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6477844)