# getting null pointer execption when using "ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()" below is my code

Tags: java

This is my code I am getting nullpointer exception at `JavaCompiler javaCompiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();` line as per given example on stackoverflow I got some said to set "java.home" explicitly however I am getting same issue.

```
File dir = new File("d://Hello.java");

File[] javaFiles = dir.new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File file, String name) {
        return name.endsWith(".java");
    }
});

String home= System.getProperty("java.home");

System.out.println(""+home.replace("\\jre",""));

System.setProperty("java.home", home);

JavaCompiler javaCompiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();


DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = javaCompiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, Locale.US,Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays.asList(javaFiles));
javaCompiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, null, null, compilationUnits).call();

for (Diagnostic diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()) {
    System.out.format("Error on line %d in %d%n", diagnostic.getLineNumber(), diagnostic.getSource().toString());
}        

fileManager.close();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Null Pointer Exception while using Java Compiler API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543439/null-pointer-exception-while-using-java-compiler-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I got the issue ,this is because of different version of Tools.jar
I was using different Tools.jar in my class path as I was using **JDK 1.7** but using **Tools.jar 1.6** version.
Now it is fixed !!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might run into  [this known problem](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6477844). Try to use JRE instead of JDK.

If you are already using JRE, then try to specifically include tools.jar into your library.

*As stated by Jon Skeet in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2543485/4391450)*

Comment: I have tried but got same issue again and again ,already include tools.jar in classpath

Comment: Oh OK, the piece of code that seems dodgy to me is set system property on the runtime `System.setProperty("java.home", home)`, I have never done that but in order not to fall into my own personal credulity fallacy, I would recommend you to have a thorough test on that bit.

Comment: I was not using System.setProperty("java.home", home) in my code but I got an example on stackoverflow to use it, issue is still same if I remove it

Comment: @Pawan I just did a quick check and it works. My environment is: Java 6, Windows 10. And are you running in Eclipse or other IDE? You can also check if JDK of your IDE is pointing to the correct place.

Comment: I am using jdk 7 and running this program in Netbeans and windows 7