# How to generate bytecode of existing class at Runtime in Java?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

How to generate bytecode of existing class at Runtime in Java?

My Existing class is say `Foo.java`

```
public class Foo {

    public String saySomething() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Now I want to generate byte code of this existing class `Foo.java` and probably use it in another instance of JVM. Please understand I am not creating a class at runtime since I already have an existing class called `Foo.java`. Open to any libraries such as ASM or ByteBuddy etc.

Comment: If the class does already exist, just load it? If it is not on the classpath then a new classloader might help. Or do you really need the bytes of that class (or the byte code), then explain for what.

Comment: I really need bytes of that class. similar to this https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/compile

Comment: This is contradictory. In the comment you present a function that transforms bytes to a class object, not a class to a byte object. maybe it would help if you explain for what you need this.

Comment: Where? I always wanted an existing class to byte object at runtime.

Comment: yes I meant I need bytecode of my `Foo.java` class above at runtime

Comment: The `compile` function from python does exactly the other way yet. It transforms bytes to a class object.

Comment: You may refer to https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-compile-a-class-at-runtime-with-java-8-and

Comment: @CoronA That's an incorrect statement. compile function in python takes the source code and compile to bytecode at runtime. I had done it so many times.

Comment: Better refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544446/how-do-you-dynamically-compile-and-load-external-java-classes

Comment: @MillerCyChan You got it! I am exactly looking for this. I wonder why this isn't part of standard Java package but anyways can you please tell me if this line `JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();` will invoke some external binary outside of JVM? or it is just a library function that takes a source and returns a bytecode?

Comment: JDK is required, so it will invoke javac outside of JVM according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46096598/toolprovider-getsystemjavacompiler-always-returning-null-using-jdk

Comment: @MillerCyChan Thanks a lot. Is there any way to do this without invoking an external binary like javac? I just need the bytecode IR representation right which is machine independent so does it really need to invoke javac?

Comment: At least the jre is required, please look up the words "First I used the jre again" from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46096598/toolprovider-getsystemjavacompiler-always-returning-null-using-jdk

Answer (score 0):

**[Edited following the clarification in the comments]**

The [following article](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-compile-a-class-at-runtime-with-java-8-and) describes how to compile a class from source code at runtime, using `ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()`.

Comment: `Loads a given file (presumably .class) into a byte array` This assume I already have a .class file but that is not the case I have a Foo.java so I need to be able to compile at runtime and get the bytecode at runtime. In python this is very easy.

Comment: See getClass(String name) in the same article, for getting the file name from the full class name

Comment: i need something like this https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/compile

Comment: I edited the answer to answer the missing bits arising from your questions.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure if you follow my question. I want to go from existing Foo.java class to byte code at runtime Not bytecode to Class.

Comment: What do you mean by "at runtime"? If you are running a compiled java program, you have the .class already, otherwise, how is it 'runtime'? The code above shows you how to get the bytecode (as a byte array that can be turned into string) from a class at runtime.

Comment: I want the compilation to happen at runtime and get the bytecode as a result so I can print the bytecode on screen lets say.

Comment: I see. Take a look at this then: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-compile-a-class-at-runtime-with-java-8-and

Comment: You got it! I am exactly looking for this. I wonder why this isn't part of standard Java package but anyways can you please tell me if this line JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler(); will invoke some external binary outside of JVM? or it is just a library function that takes a source and returns a bytecode?

Comment: ToolProvider is part of rt.jar, which is part of the JVM, but the compiler itself is provided by the platform. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html#getSystemJavaCompiler--

Comment: Reading from the comments above. Is there any way to do this without invoking an external binary like javac? I just need the bytecode IR representation right which is machine independent so does it really need to invoke external binary like javac?

Comment: The bytecode is machine independent, but you still need a some kind of compiler to get it from a source code, don't you?

Comment: yes but the question really is does the compiler have to be an external binary in this case? can it just be a library function?

Comment: From the decompiled code (see next comment), it does seem like a library, but I won't be surprised if this implementation is only available with a JDK, and not with a JRE.

Comment: public static JavaCompiler getSystemJavaCompiler() {
        return (JavaCompiler)instance().getSystemTool(JavaCompiler.class, "com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool");
    }

Comment: Can you please update your answer then? using JavaCompiler getSystemJavaCompiler()  and getting the bytecode of class like Foo.java above

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a library for that, any class file is just a resource just like any other file which can be located by `Foo.class.getResource("Foo.class")`. You can open a stream of this resource and read its byte just as of any other resource.

If you are already using Byte Buddy, you can get hold of the bytes by: `ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.read(Foo.class)` but if that is all you need, using a library would be an overkill.