# Is it possible to subtype a class without creating a subclass?

Tags: java

Suppose I have a class `Thing` and some function/method that accepts a thing `myFunction(Thing x)`. I want to create a class `Thing2` which can be passed into `myFunction`, and which replicates the interface of `Thing` by supporting all the same public methods and fields etc. One way to do this would be to have `Thing2` be a subclass of `Thing`. But is there a way to have `Thing2` be a subtype of `Thing` without making it a subclass — for example, if I don't want `Thing2` to inherit private fields of `Thing`?

And if it is not possible using regular Java, is it possible to do so by generating Java bytecode via some other means?

I am asking this question purely out of curiosity, I don't actually have a specific problem that I am trying to solve.

Comment: It sounds like you should really have an interface to implement...

Comment: @JonSkeet Of course, I agree that that would be better for real-world code. I am simply asking because I am curious about whether the JVM implementation details would allow this.

Comment: *"if I don't want `Thing2` to inherit private fields of `Thing`?"* how does a subclass in inherit private fields? Am I missing something?

Comment: If  Java class "Thing2" inherits from super class "Thing2" ... then Thing2 *IS* a subclass.  Period.  Full stop.  ALTERNATIVES: Yes, you can generate bytecode on the fly:. 
 For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52867815/.  Better, it sounds like you simply want an "interface": https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: *"for example, if I don't want Thing2 to inherit private fields of Thing?"* Lousy example, since private members are not inherited anyway.

Comment: If you don't use inheritance then you won't be able to pass _Thing2_ to  _myFunction_.  Possibly add an example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: First, if `Thing` is a class and you pass to your method an object that is not a `Thing` or a subclass of `Thing`, then you are getting a compile-time error. No way to avoid that. Second, it hardly applies to your imagined situation, but there are two cases where a subtype of a class type is not a subclass: (1) E.g., `ArrayList<? extends Integer>` is a subtype of `ArrayList<? extends Number>` but is still the same class, not a subclass. Wildcards in generics allow many such cases. (2) The type of `null` is a subtype of any type, so also a subtype of `Thing`. So yes, pass `null` .

Answer (score 3):

This is *exactly* what the D in [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) is talking about. The D stands for [Dependency inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), and it can be phrased as: "Abstractions should not depend on concrete implementations".

What you have is a function that takes a `Thing`. A concrete class. But what you really *want* is a function that takes "anything that happens to support my `frobnicate()` method". That means the function has the wrong signature. If the function only requires a specific interface, then you want an `interface` in Java. Rather than

```
public class Thing {
  private Foo lotsOfImplementationDetails;

  public void frobnicate() {
    ...
  }
}

void myFunction(Thing x) {
  // All I want is frobnicate(), but I depend on the *whole* state.
  ...
}
```

consider

```
public interface Frobnicatable {
  public void frobnicate();
}

public class Thing implements Frobnicatable {
  private Foo lotsOfImplementationDetails;

  @Override
  public void frobnicate() {
    ...
  }
}

void myFunction(Frobnicatable x) {
  // Anything will work, provided it has the right method.
  ...
}
```

Comment: I agree with everything you said but this really doesn't answer my question. I am asking a conceptual question about the JVM out of curiosity, not asking about what kinds of design patterns are good for actual code which one might use.

Comment: I see. I can't really prove a negative, but I'm not aware of a way to make an unrelated class `Thing2` masquerade as an instance of `Thing` on the JVM. All casts are checked at the VM level, so there's no equivalent to C++'s extremely unsafe `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo, _"frobnicate"_, where did you possibly find this word?

Comment: @Relias One of my professors used it. It's my go-to word for "generic unnamed action", sort of my `foo` / `bar` but as a verb.